# How to call a function inside another function in Typescript Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps, typescript, ionic-framework

I am new to Angular 2. I wrote below code in Angular

```
export class TestClass {

    constructor() {
        this.initMap();
    }

    initMap() {
        this.marker.addListener('dragend', this.onMarkerDrop);
    }

    onMarkerDrop(event) {
        this.functionTwo(); // Getting error this.functionTwo is not a function
    }

    functionTwo() {

    }
}
```

**Note:** Before asking this question I searched in stackoverflow I got these links

['this.function' is not a function - OO JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43022556/this-function-is-not-a-function-oo-js)

[this.function is not a function :typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45662841/this-function-is-not-a-function-typescript)

[Angular - this.function is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48808626/angular-this-function-is-not-a-function)

They are saying that use Arrow functions to call other member functions.
But I don't know how to implement their suggestions in my code. Might I didn't understood them correctly.

I want help from you like, how to call this.functionTwo() using arrow function from functionOne();

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This will work 100% fine , there should be something more than this code

Comment: This much of code will work for sure. Give some more details.

Comment: you are sending the function as a callback.. use bind. `this.marker.addListener('dragend', this.onMarkerDrop.bind(this));`

Comment: Hi VivekDoshi and Arun Raj R, thank you for your response. I have updated my code, Please check once. Actually in the function on onMarkerDrop() I am getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `onMarkerDrop` is passed as a callback where the context *will change* and `this` will have a different value. Use arrow or bind while sending to preserve context.

```
this.marker.addListener('dragend', this.onMarkerDrop.bind(this));
```

or

```
this.marker.addListener('dragend', ($event)=>this.onMarkerDrop($event));
```

Answer (score 6):

**As per your code updation , you can use it like :**

```
this.marker.addListener('dragend', this.onMarkerDrop.bind(this));
// OR
this.marker.addListener('dragend', ($event) => this.onMarkerDrop($event));
```

---

**Your code will work 100% fine : (Before Question Updated)**

```
functionOne() {
    this.functionTwo(); // Getting error this.functionTwo is not a function
}

functionTwo() {
    alert('function2');
}
```

**Please check the below code for more clarification**

```
functionOne() {
    // this will throw error this.functionTwo is not a function
    setTimeout(function(){ // normal function
        this.functionTwo();  
    })

    // This wont throw the error
    setTimeout(() => { // fat arrow
        this.functionTwo(); // Getting error this.functionTwo is not a function        
    })
}

functionTwo() {
    alert('function2');
}
```

> Why it will work with **[fat arrow](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_arrow-functions.html)** :
>
> this is picked up from surroundings (lexical). Therefore, you don’t
>   need `bind()` or `that = this`, anymore.
>
> With Normal function you need to do `bind()` or `that = this`

Comment: Hi @Vivek Doshi, Thank you for your answer. But I've updated my question. Can you please check once.

Comment: @VivekDoshi your arrow function example is incorrect